# Uploading a file from python application to appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to upload a file from a python application that runs on my pc to an appengine app hosted on appengine.

Suppose I have a file foo.txt which I want to upload to appengine, hypothetically I could make this totally ridiculous GET request to this url from my python script on pc.

```
http://appid.appspot.com/?file=foo.txt
```

Since url length is limited to roughly 2000 characters, it wont be possible to pass the file as a GET request, so will have to make a POST request.

**How do I make the POST request to appengine app and send the file as a parameter ?**

and then handle the request on appengine as follows,

```
class MainHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.response.write(blob_info)
```

I know this won't work, what is the correct way to do this.
Is there any better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works for me for giving a pdf download to the user. Once you read the uploaded file in a StringIO object, you can use this to provide the download.

```
outputStream = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write(outputStream) #write merged output to the StringIO object

fname = 'filename'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + fname + '.pdf'
self.response.write(outputStream.getvalue())
```

Then, from your appengine app, you can read this response, store it as a StringIO object and use the google file API to store it as a disk file.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196947/gae-python-form-file-upload-email-file-as-attachment) SO link to learn how to get an uploaded file into a StringIO object.

To know how exactly I generate this pdf before writing the output, read my [entire article](http://www.prahladyeri.com/2013/11/how-to-generate-pdf-in-python-for-google-app-engine/).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be aware of the Blobstore ... the question you're asking is specifically addressed in the docs.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob